# Displaying subsets of a set using 0 for absent elements

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to write an algorithm in C++. Suppose we have x={1,2,3,4}. Then as a result:

```
1 2 3 0
1 2 0 4
1 0 3 4
0 2 3 4
1 2 0 0
1 0 3 0
0 2 3 0
1 0 0 4
...
0 2 0 0
1 0 0 0
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you show what you tried?

Comment: what is the algorithm doing? this looks like some sort of binary-code.

Comment: Lets find the `magic wand`!

Comment: I'd suggest using recursion, you could write function like replaceCharWith0(std::string&, int index), inside you replace the char, print/save resulting string and loop over remaining string length..

Comment: Actually I feel going iterative through the function, and just use a bitmask should be the simplest approach to this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a binary representation of a 4-bit number. So you're incrementing this number and use it as a mask to apply to `1 2 3 4`. I hope you don't want us to write all the code for you. Feel free to ask if something is not clear.

Comment: Ok, and what if we have 5 or 10 numbers?

Comment: You just dont grasp the idea behind it?? Try to understand what he is doing there, or take my code, and go through it in the bloody debugger.

Comment: @user2545986, If we have 5 numbers, we will use 5-bit number for mask. 1 bit of mask representing 1 number in given array

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is something fairly simple:

```
std::vector<int> x; 
/* set x to { 1,2,3,4 } */

std::vector<int> temp(x.size());
byte mask = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < (int)pow(2, x.size()); ++i)
{
   for(int j = 0; j < x.length(); ++j)
   {
       mask = ; // this is the tricky part, set it to bit j of i
       temp.at(j) = x.at(j) * mask;
   }
}
```

Comment: The question looks like learning task, I don't think it's a good idea to provide code, or author will learn nothing from it

Comment: Okay, I edited the one tricky part of the question out. Actually there is another error in it, when looking at the original question, so he will have to look through that as well.

Comment: @AntonRoth just so you know it's `size()` and not `length()`, the parameter types for `pow` are wrong (`size()` returns `size_t`) and you used the short circuit `&&` instead of the bitwise `&` in your original code

Comment: There should be a compiler warning against writing (int)pow(2,n), I can't find any good reason to spell operator<< this way.

Comment: Meh, that's all that stupid stuff you'll notice during first debug run. The && vs & though wouldnt have made a difference, but true, I wrote down the wrong one.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: That was one of the things I did wrong intentionally. I knew that that line would at least cause compiler warnings, but I think it should even result in an error. The code was supposed to be wrong to some extent, and not entirely efficient.

Comment: @AntonRoth oh but `&&` versus `&` does make a difference, `01b && 10b = true` aka 1 while `01b & 10b = 00b`

Comment: Okay, right, didn't think of that.